# Entity class made with make:entity not recognized in Controller despite use namespace

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

In **Symfony 4**, using `bin/console` I've created new Entity:

```
php bin/console make:entity Being
...
```

It created `Entity/Being.php` and `Repository\BeingRepository.php` files.

Later I've also used `make:migration` and `doctrine:migration:migrate`, and my changes are now visible in database.

The problem is, when I wrote simple controller in `Controller/DefaultController.php`:

```
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Being;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{

/**
 * @Route("/", name="blog_index")
 */
public function index()
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $beings =  $entityManager->getRepository(Being::class);
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig',
        ["beings" => $beings->findAll()]);
}
}
```

I get error:

> Class 'App\Entity\Being' does not exist

I also tried changing `Being` to explictly `\App\Entity\Being` with same result.

Note that I've not touched the files created by `make:entity` (`Entity/Being.php` and `Repository\BeingRepository.php`). First one looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BeingRepository")
 */
class Being
{
...
```

**Do I miss something?**

Comment: Assuming you are using the default composer.json with PSR-4 autoloading, you will need to run `php bin\console cache:clear` and `php bin\console cache:warmup`, ensure you restart `php-fpm` if using `apcu` or `opcache`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Assuming that your entity file is src/Entity/Being.php and that you are in development mode then you really should not have to fool around with composer or cache clearing.  Especially since the migrate worked.  Does your IDE recognize the entity?  All I can think of is that you have a spelling error some place.

Answer (score 1):

Try just to execute composer `dump-autoload` or simply `composer dumpa` in console. In most cases it helps.

```
composer dumpa
```